# Get core temp in Java

Tags: sensor, java

I want to e.g., see my temperature and do something if it reaches a threshold. In java. I mean from the built in SoC sensor not an external one.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp.

Read the single line as an integer.

Close the file.

Divide the read value by 1000 to get degrees centigrade.

E.g. a read value of 37932 is 37.932 degrees centigrade.